# Indentation is messed up when pasting code

Tags: cut-copy-paste, indentation

I find that the default indentation support for pasting is lacking.
For example ,
If I use `]p` for the following(copied using `V`) :

```
        try:
            l=None
            if 1:
                df = vcbcvbcvb

            return l, df
```

When I am over this line:

```
def save(fn):
```

I get the same thing but when the try at all not indented .

```
def save(fn):
try:
    l=None
    if 1:
        df = vcbcvbcvb

    return l, df
```

Now , I tried to fix it by:

```
nnoremap <expr> ]p @+ =~ ".*\n$" ?  "]p==" : "o<C-R>+<ESC>"
```

which is not enough because the `==` should be on all the pasted text.

Is there a plugin that does complete support or could you suggest just a concrete solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found myself implementing the code.

It first pastes then fixes the indentation correctly as far as I could see.

```
function! PasteFormat(x)
    let l=@+
    let l=len(split(l,"\n"))-1
    return a:x."V".string(l).'j='
endfunction

nnoremap <expr> ]p @+ =~ ".*\n$" ?  PasteFormat("p") : "o<C-R>+<ESC>"
nnoremap <expr> ]P @+ =~ ".*\n$" ?  PasteFormat("P") : "O<C-R>+<ESC>"
```